# Go to the next page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem regarding displaying the next page on a Website.
I use jQuery and want to Display the next Page if the Enter key is pressed?
How can I accomplish that.
The code below shows already what I have written.
Is there any method that will do fine?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e){

        if(e.which == 13){



        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Is there a "next page" button on the website? If so, could you inspect element on it and see what it's calling when it's clicked? Cheers

Comment: Unfortunatly not because the Code run on ab website where we can´t create own buttons

Comment: Okay no worries, what type of webpage is it? I'm just wondering what would normally trigger a "next page" so we can try and replicate that in code

Comment: One approach is the using the History API. This is also commonly used on SPAs.

Comment: Its  called Socisurvey a website for psychological surveys which allows you to write own Html Code but limted for security reasons.

Comment: What is "next page" referring to? Do you have some sample code for that?

Comment: look at [the answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage). Also look a this [solution on codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1111895/Create-next-previous-HTML-page-navigation-with-jqu) Setting the window.location is the basis of both answers..

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.location for redirect to another page:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com" // set your next page url instead of www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); or

           window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; or

           window.open(url, '_blank');
```